# Unable to Refresh BCS External Data

Tags: bcs, external-content-type, odata, secure-store, refresh

I am running into a refresh issue with BCS. Whenever I hit the little refresh button in the UI, I am repeatedly getting this error.

I am using an OData web service for BCS with WindowsCredentials authentication via the secure store.

[image]

Log error indicates the following:

> Connection manager did not return valid connection. Error Message: 'Access is denied to the Secure Store Service.'. LOBSystem: 'WsTest1' LOBSytemInstance: 'WsTest1' Entity: 'Employee' Method: 'Read Specific Employee'

Anyone have any ideas where I can begin troubleshooting?

**UPDATE:** Some new information.

For "Member" permissions on my secure store ID, I included my account and the "Everyone, except external users" account.

When I add the "Everyone" account, the refresh works.

So now the question is, what is included in "Everyone", that is not included in "Everyone, except external users" that is tied to BDC calls?